# How to use regularizer argument in tf.get_variable?

Tags: tensorflow

The syntax of the usage is clear:

```
decay = tf.constant(0.001, dtype=tf.float32)
w = tf.get_variable(name='weight', shape=[512, 512],
                    regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(decay))
```

However, in the documentation only the following is stated:

> `regularizer`: A (Tensor -> Tensor or None) function; the result of applying it on a newly created variable will be added to the collection `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` and can be used for regularization.

The above does not imply that the regularization loss is automatically minimized. So do we need to manually get the variable from the collection  `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` and add it to our main loss in order for it to be applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So do we need to manually get the variable from the collection  tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES and add it to our main loss in order for it to be applied?

Yes, and no: You need to manually get the regularization losses via [`tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/get_regularization_loss) (this will already get all regularization losses defined in the collection, no need to search for the variables in it), then you simply add the regularization loss to your model's loss and use that as the loss your optimizer trains on:

```
logits = model_fn(inputs)
model_loss = your_chosen_loss_function(logits)
regularization_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
your_chosen_optimizer.minimize(model_loss + regularization_loss)
```

Comment: Correction: `get_regularization_losses` returns a _list_ of losses; you can't add this to your loss directly. Instead, `get_regularization_loss` returns a tensor that is the sum of all regularization losses. This one can be used directly.

Comment: Aha! Good catch @xdurch0, I overlooked the singular vs plural versions! I'll amend the answer right away, thanks!